# Could not get disqus to work with jekyll and git pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, disqus

I am using Github Pages and Jekyll. I added the Disqus configuration but it could not appear on the posts. 
I added disqus.html in the _includes directory. and added my disqus shortname into _config.yml. 
Called {% include disqus.html %} from _layout/post.html.
Tried the comment:true option in the markdown files as well.

You may view my work at:
 https://github.com/motleis/weekActivities

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: So far, I tried to converge the problem and noticed that {% if site.disqus %} is not evaluated to true. The only thing I can think of is filling the 'disqus' parameter in the _config.yml. 
Any other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured this out!!

"put your short-name inside quotation marks!"